# onclick event on Box is not working using JQuery

Tags: jquery, click

jQuery don't work example https://jsfiddle.net/ladysilvia/oc1xhczq/
the jquery script should individually open a box with a click.
does not work

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // hide all the events
  $("figure.back").css('display', 'none');
  $("a.tagTarget").click(function() {
    //    $(this, "back").parent().parent().toggleClass('back front');
  });
  // close box
  $(".box-close").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut();
  });
  $('a.tagTarget').click(function() {
    $(".back").css('display', 'block');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="event">

    <figure class="front">
      <div class="card-hor-reveal">
        <a class="tagTarget toggle-reval-click btn-floating-30 white" href="#">
          <i class="ion-pricetag">up</i>
        </a>
        <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4 left">Front 1</span><i class="right ion-android-cancel"></i>
        <p>tag e altre info su Card.</p>
      </div>
    </figure>

  </li>

  <li class="event">

    <figure class="back">
      <div class="card-hor-reveal">
        <a class="box-close btn-floating-30 white" href="#">
          <i class="ion-pricetag">x</i>
        </a>

        <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4 left">back 1</span><i class="right ion-android-cancel"></i>
        <p>tag e altre info su Card.</p>
      </div>
    </figure>
  </li>

  <li class="event">

    <figure class="front">
      <div class="card-hor-reveal">
        <a class="tagTarget toggle-reval-click btn-floating-30 white" href="#">
          <i class="ion-pricetag">up</i>
        </a>
        <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4 left">Front 2</span><i class="right ion-android-cancel"></i>
        <p>tag e altre info su Card.</p>
      </div>
    </figure>
  </li>

  <li class="event">
    <figure class="back">
      <div class="card-hor-reveal">
        <a class="box-close btn-floating-30 white" href="#">
          <i class="ion-pricetag">x</i>
        </a>

        <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4 left">back 2 </span><i class="right ion-android-cancel"></i>
        <p>tag e altre info su Card.</p>
      </div>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li class="event">
    <figure class="front">
      <div class="card-hor-reveal">
        <a class="tagTarget toggle-reval-click btn-floating-30 white" href="#">
          <i class="ion-pricetag">up</i>
        </a>
        <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4 left">Front 3</span><i class="right ion-android-cancel"></i>
        <p>tag e altre info su Card.</p>
      </div>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li class="event">
    <figure class="back">
      <div class="card-hor-reveal">
        <a class="box-close btn-floating-30 white" href="#">
          <i class="ion-pricetag">x</i>
        </a>

        <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4 left">back 3</span><i class="right ion-android-cancel"></i>
        <p>tag e altre info su Card.</p>
      </div>
    </figure>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: Why did you edited the question, Its not readable anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use current element context i.e. `this` and various DOM traversal methods to target the specific `figure.back` element

As `back` is child of parent `li` element use [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to traverse up to it, then use `.next()` to get following `li`, then use `.find()` to target the desired element.

*Use*

```
$('a.tagTarget').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.event').next('.event').find(".back").css('display', 'block');
});
```

*instead of*

```
$('a.tagTarget').click(function() {
  $(".back").css('display', 'block');
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/oc1xhczq/2/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // hide all the events
  $("figure.back").css('display', 'none');
  // chiudi il box
  $(".box-close").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut();
  });

  $('a.tagTarget').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.event').next('.event').find(".back").css('display', 'block');
  });
});
```

```css
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.front {
  background-color: #ffcccc;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px 20px 0 20px;
}
.back {
  background-color: #ff00cc;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 20px;
}
.btn-floating-30 {
  display: inline-table;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: none;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  background-color: #26a69a;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 2px;
  text-align: center;
}
.btn-floating-30:hover {
  background-color: #26a69a
}
.btn-floating-30 {
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="event">

    <figure class="front">
      <div class="card-hor-reveal">
        <a class="tagTarget toggle-reval-click btn-floating-30 white" href="#">
          <i class="ion-pricetag">up</i>
        </a>
        <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4 left">Front 1</span><i class="right ion-android-cancel"></i>
        <p>tag e altre info su Card.</p>
      </div>
    </figure>

  </li>

  <li class="event">

    <figure class="back">
      <div class="card-hor-reveal">
        <a class="box-close btn-floating-30 white" href="#">
          <i class="ion-pricetag">x</i>
        </a>

        <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4 left">back 1</span><i class="right ion-android-cancel"></i>
        <p>tag e altre info su Card.</p>
      </div>
    </figure>
  </li>

  <li class="event">

    <figure class="front">
      <div class="card-hor-reveal">
        <a class="tagTarget toggle-reval-click btn-floating-30 white" href="#">
          <i class="ion-pricetag">up</i>
        </a>
        <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4 left">Front 2</span><i class="right ion-android-cancel"></i>
        <p>tag e altre info su Card.</p>
      </div>
    </figure>
  </li>

  <li class="event">
    <figure class="back">
      <div class="card-hor-reveal">
        <a class="box-close btn-floating-30 white" href="#">
          <i class="ion-pricetag">x</i>
        </a>

        <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4 left">back 2 </span><i class="right ion-android-cancel"></i>
        <p>tag e altre info su Card.</p>
      </div>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li class="event">
    <figure class="front">
      <div class="card-hor-reveal">
        <a class="tagTarget toggle-reval-click btn-floating-30 white" href="#">
          <i class="ion-pricetag">up</i>
        </a>
        <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4 left">Front 3</span><i class="right ion-android-cancel"></i>
        <p>tag e altre info su Card.</p>
      </div>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li class="event">
    <figure class="back">
      <div class="card-hor-reveal">
        <a class="box-close btn-floating-30 white" href="#">
          <i class="ion-pricetag">x</i>
        </a>

        <span class="card-title grey-text text-darken-4 left">back 3</span><i class="right ion-android-cancel"></i>
        <p>tag e altre info su Card.</p>
      </div>
    </figure>
  </li>
</ul>
```

References

1. [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)
2. [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)
3. [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)